# ansible: dict object' has no attribute with when defined

Tags: ansible

I have this property file:

```
addresses:
  AAA:
    type: "anycast"
    queues:
      - queue_name: "AAA.bbb"
        queue_filter: "'%aaaa%'"
  BBB:
    type: "multicast"
    queues:
      - queue_name:  "BBB.ccc"
        queue_filter: "'%cccc%'"
      - queue_name: "RRR.wwww"
        queue_filter: "'%wwww%'"
        max_redelivery_delay: "30000"
        max_delivery_attempts: "1500"
        expiry_delay: "172800000"
```

This is my ansible code:

```
  - name: configure - clustering - addresses - settings
    xml:
      path: "/tmp/broker.xml"
      xpath: "/conf:configuration/core:core/core:address-settings/core:address-setting[@match='{{ item.0.key }}::{{ item.1.queue_name }}']"
      add_children:
        - max-redelivery-delay: "{{ item.1.max_redelivery_delay }}"
      namespaces:
        conf: urn:activemq
        core: urn:activemq:core
      pretty_print: yes
      when: item.1.max_redelivery_delay is defined
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ addresses|dict2items }}"
      - value.queues
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Now I get this error:

```
TASK [configure - clustering - addresses - settings] ******************************************
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'max_redelivery_delay'\n\nThe error appears to be in 'test5.yaml': line 58, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: configure - clustering - addresses - settings\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Why do I get this error, max_redelivery_delay is not defined for the queue AAA.bbb and BBB.ccc but is defined for RRR.wwww.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"*The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'max_redelivery_delay'*"**

The indentation is wrong. *when* is considered an attribute of the module *xml*

```yaml
      when: item.1.max_redelivery_delay is defined
    with_subelements:
```

Correct

```yaml
    when: item.1.max_redelivery_delay is defined
    with_subelements:
```